# Spring boot + gradle - H2 db is not accessible with 404 error

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, h2, h2db

My H2 web interface is not accessible. Though Java code can get data but web interface is failing to connect to it. This started happening after I rebooted my system.

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue May 02 21:34:04 PDT 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Gradle File: build.gradle:-

```
buildscript {
        ext {
            springBootVersion = '1.4.4.RELEASE'
        }
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        }
    }

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

    jar {
        baseName = 'cg'
        version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

    }

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }


    dependencies {
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
        compile ("commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp")   
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
        runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
        runtime('com.h2database:h2')
        testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    }
```

Comment: Provide more information. pom.xml will be a good start.

Comment: I resolve issue of slow loading of web service . I dont know what happened but I rename the bootApplication class and it stated in 5 seconds

Comment: Dont have pom file just gradle file:

Comment: default spring boot will give h2db jars. use the @restcontroller in controllers then  concern service. and give the h2db database setting in application.properties file

Comment: I think I have that setting as it was working fine earlier.    application.properties looks as:logging.level.org.springframework.web=INFO
server.port=8080
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:challenge
spring.datasource.schema=classpath:/schema.sql
spring.datasource.data=classpath:/data.sql

Comment: can you provide more info so that we help you out....

Comment: please add this dependency  - compile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.3.148'